# Equivalent CFG(context free grammar) without null production

Tags: automata

For the grammar given below,what is the equivalent CFG without null productions?

```
S->ASB/epsilon
A->Aa/epsilon
B->bB/epsilon.
```

Comment: You will need at least one null production, because the language includes the empty string. You can remove null productions by examining how they work. For example, `A` yields `a*`. You can express `aa*` as `A->Aa|a`. Then you just need a mechanism to make `A` itself optional. `A` is specified in `S`, so you can remove it from there in one of the productions: `S->ASB|SB|epsilon`.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that if X := epsilon, we can change any production Y := rXs into Y := rXs | rs and eliminate the production X := epsilon. Let's see how that works in your case. First, we can to S.

```
S -> ASB | epsilon … becomes … S -> ASB | AB
A -> Aa | epsilon
B -> bB | epsilon
```

Now we do A:

```
S -> ASB | AB … becomes … S -> ASB | SB | AB | B
A -> Aa | epsilon … becomes … A -> Aa | a
B -> bB | epsilon
```

Now we do B:

```
S -> ASB | SB | AB | B … becomes … S -> ASB | AS | SB | AB | A | B | epsilon
A -> Aa | a
B -> bB | b
```

We can't get rid of S -> epsilon since the empty string is generated by the input grammar.